# How do you use the verb "costar" in a question (meaning "difficult" or "hard")

Tags: gramática, verbos

How do you use the verb "costar" in a question when it means "difficult" or "hard".
For example, how would you say

> "Was it hard to begin this project?"

and

> "What do you find difficult about this project?"

using the verb "costar"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is off-topic: please check [What topics can I ask about here](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (section on translation), with additional details [here](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2673/debemos-replantearnos-los-motivos-de-cierre-espec%C3%ADficos-del-sitio-para-que-sean): **Questions asking for translations are off-topic unless prior research effort is clearly indicated; we're here to help you learn, not provide a bulk translation service.**

Anyway, here are my 2 cents:

> 1) "¿Te ha costado ...?"
>   2) "¿Qué te ha costado ... ?"

But you should also consider whether you should use "tú", "le", "os", "vos", etc.